# Running a MATLAB file several times

Tags: matlab

I am working on a research work on wireless transmission of signals. The signal is affected by noise and small scale fading. The normalized mean square error (NMSE) is used to estimate the quality of the reconstructed signal at the receiver. When I run the same *.m* file in MATLAB several times, I obtain different values for the NMSE, although the same channel signal to noise ratio is used.

I knew that the solution to this problem is to run the file several times and take the average. This is used to avoid the large variance introduced by the limited number of experiments. My problem is that running the file many times takes too long, how can I do this in MATLAB easily?

Comment: Assuming you are already using a loop to run the code many times. There are not a lot of things you can do to reduce the run time. Firstly, you can post your code here and maybe we can suggest you some functions that could be speeded up in your script. Otherwise you can implement some parallel tool such as *parfor* that reduce the run time executing loop iterations in parallel.

Comment: How many times shall I run the code?

Comment: Maybe not feasible for you, but you might want to consider implementing your model in Julia (http://julialang.org), it's almost as easy as Matlab but a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop! The format of code should be something like the following:

```
run_length = 1e5; % or any desired number which is sufficiently large
NMSE_vector = zeros(run_length,1); % the vector you use in the loop

% any other code here

for r=1:run_length
   % generate a random message,
   % add noise and communicate over the channel
   % receive the noisy message
   % reconstruct the message and calculate NMMS

   NMSE_vector(r) = NMSE;
end
average_NMSE = mean(NMSE_vector);
```

I also recommend considering MATLAB's parallel processing toolbox, in case if your Monte Carlo simulation is really huge...

Comment: How many times shall I run the code?

Comment: There is not a rule for that. It depends how many precision digits you are looking for. More times you run and average, more precision you get.